# Как искать фотографии по геолокации и дате в блогах и социальных сетях?

Tags: изображения, поиск, соцсети

Существует ли сервис для поиска изображений в FB, VK, Twitter, Instagram, Flikr, Odnoklassniki (в идеале уметь включать в поиск любые ресурсы).

С функциями поиска:

- геолокация - от 10 метров;
- период публикации, глубина просмотра дальше 1 месяца;
- запрос по ключевым словам;
- консистентность выборки при повторных запросах;
- export результатов (ссылка на источник) для последующего анализа;

В найденных ресурсах ограниченный функционал. Или поиск по 1, 2 ресурсам, или нет фильтров по датам.

Существуют ли готовые решения или надо создавать?

Comment: Вот несколько существующих примеров: http://photo-map.ru/ 
http://www.yomapic.com/ru/ 
http://grenki.com/

Comment: И еще: http://www.social-searcher.com/  http://photo-locator.ru/